# In C++, cout is not printing the output when a function is call from another file to main file

Tags: c++, function, printing, output, cout

Here I have created three files named,

1. main.cpp (Main file)

```
#include"practicals.hpp"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    firstPractical;
    return 0;
}
```

2. practicals.hpp (Custom header file)

```
#ifndef PRACTICAL_HPP
#define PRACTICAL_HPP
#pragma once
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void firstPractical();

#endif
```

3. firstPractical.cpp (File containing my function)

```
#include <iostream>
#include "practicals.hpp"

using namespace std;

void firstPractical() {
    cout << "First Practical" << endl;
}
```

Here, I have called the 'firstPractical' function from *firstPractical.cpp* in *main.cpp* file using *practicals.hpp* header file. So, when I tried to run the file, it should print the 'First Practical' in output. Insted, it does not print anything in output.

Output:

```
[Running] cd "d:\CD\CD Practicals\New folder\" && g++ main.cpp -o main && "d:\CD\CD Practicals\New folder\"main

[Done] exited with code=0 in 0.27 seconds
```

**So, what's the problem with my code?**

Comment: You forgot to call your function. In `main`, `firstPractical;` should be `firstPractical();`. If you enabled compiler warnings, your compiler could at least try to tell you what's wrong ([see it online](https://godbolt.org/z/17zn9oM1o) with warnings enabled)

Comment: If I add parenthesis then it gives me this error, C:\Users\hussa\AppData\Local\Temp\cc47fmlc.o:main.cpp:(.text+0xe): undefined reference to `firstPractical()' collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: One bug  is here: `g++ main.cpp -o main` the VSCode documentation tells you how to fix that here: [https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw#_modifying-tasksjson](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw#_modifying-tasksjson)

Comment: @HussainGandhi Look at how you build your program `g++ main.cpp -o main` There is no mention of the file `firstPractical.cpp` there. You need to compile and link **both** files to get a working program.

Comment: It default command generated by vs code

Comment: That is the problem. By default VSCode builds only the active file. You must follow the instructions in the documentation to have it build more than that.

Comment: @HussainGandhi Great but it is the wrong command. You need to set up VSCode so that it can handle multiple files. Amazingly enough it doesn't do this by default. Consult the VSCode documentation.

Comment: I thank you for kind suggestions :)

Answer (score 2):

you forgot the parenthesis after the function name

```cpp
int main()
{
    firstPractical();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If I add parenthesis then it gives me this error,

C:\Users\hussa\AppData\Local\Temp\cc47fmlc.o:main.cpp:(.text+0xe): undefined reference to `firstPractical()'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: @HussainGandhi -- That is a completely different error.  It has nothing to do with the syntax issue with calling the function.

Comment: `int main()
{
    void firstPractical();
    return 0;
}`
Here when I add 'void' before the call statement then no error is generated. But the problem remains same that, It is not printing any output.
`[Running] cd "d:\CD\CD Practicals\New folder\" && g++ main.cpp -o main && "d:\CD\CD Practicals\New folder\"main

[Done] exited with code=0 in 0.488 seconds`

Comment: @HussainGandhi C++ in not a language where you want to just try adding random syntax in the hope it works. `firstPractical;` vs `firstPractical();` vs `void firstPractical();` are doing completely different things. If you don't understand the difference, then you're going to have a hard to making a working program, especially if you have further errors beyond this one.